# What is this SOIC-8 part from ST?

Tags: identification, st, siemens, soic

[image: ST Microelectronics 393]

Marked "393" and "(ST)**G**Z439" or "**6**Z439" under conformal coat.

Siemens DC/DC PSU section, near a UC3843B current-mode PWM controller, HF transformer, etc.

Checked the ST [TS393ID](https://datasheet.octopart.com/TS393IDT-STMicroelectronics-datasheet-10835919.pdf) datasheet, that is a micropower dual CMOS voltage comparator.  Micropower doesn't make much sense in this application, and if it were that it should be marked "S393I".  Checked TI's [LM393D](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393.pdf?ts=1639600235708&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM393%253FkeyMatch%253DLM393%2526tisearch%253Dsearch-everything%2526usecase%253DGPN), nothing they make is marked with only "393" either.

But the other side of the two caps below it do connect to pin 4, so this seems fitting for a 393.  Is this a custom marking, custom device, or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the *ST* LM393?

https://www.st.com/en/amplifiers-and-comparators/lm393.html

There are ordering codes that are in a SOIC package and just marked "393". The second row could be manufacturing info.

[image: Ordering Codes - page 18]

Comment: Gosh, this appears to be a limitation of [Octopart](https://octopart.com/search?q=393&currency=USD&specs=0&category_id=4215&case_package=SOIC&numberofpins=8&manufacturer_id=355); it does not show ST's variant of the LM393DT, even though [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/category/integrated-circuits-ics/32?s=N4IgTCBcDaIDIFkDMBOJARAKiAugXyA) carries them.

Comment: @rdtsc, It's there if you search for LM393DT. I think your filters eliminated it from your search results because the package is listed as "SO" instead of "SOIC".